# How to implement snooze

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, macos, clock

I had design java alarm clock with digital and analoge clock .. I need a code for snooze , if snooze on (Alarm rings for one minute after every 5 minutes till the Alarm Off Button is pressed)..

else if snooze off (Alarm rings for one minute or till the Alarm Off Button is pressed during that one minute)

Comment: This is basically too broad and you haven't told us which windowing system you are using (SWT, JavaFX, Swing, ...).

Comment: i am using Swing / AWT

Answer (score 0):

When snooze starts you can either set alarm for 5 min later (since you have an alarm already it should not be a problem) or just start measuring time and start ringing when 5 minutes passed.